# when converting a python list to json and back, do you cast?

Tags: python, security, json

When you convert a list of user objects into json, and then convert it back to its original state, do you have to cast?

Are there any security issues of taking a javascript json object and converting it into a python list object?

Comment: There would only be a security issue if you `eval`'d it.

Answer (score 2):

`json.dumps(somepython)` gives you a valid JSON string representing the Python object `somepython` (which may perfectly well be a list) and `json.loads(ajsonstring)` goes the other way 'round -- both without any security issue nor "cast" (?).  That's with Python 2.6 or better, using the [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json) module in the standard library.  If you're stuck with 2.5 (e.g., for use on Google App Engine), you can use the equivalent third-party module [simplejson](http://code.google.com/p/simplejson/).

Comment: What you say isn't at all true for user defined classes. You have to implement a custom encoder to make that work.

Comment: @aaron, `json.loads` will _never_ return "user defined classes" -- there's no such thing in the JSON standard, so, isn't that obvious?  If and when you want to dump anything _but_ the JSON-defined types (and/or reload from JSON into non-JSON-defined types), therefore, obviously you need to select and code your own proprietary encoding (presumably to be made known to the Javascript on the other side of the transaction, too;-). This is not at all limited to user-defined classes, btw: plenty of Python's own built-in types (e.g., complex numbers!) are beyond the JSON standards, as well.

Comment: absolutely correct. As I should have pointed out in my original comment, OP is asking about encoding instances of user defined classes.

Answer (score 1):

You will be responsible for writing python to encode and decode your classes. How are you encoding them? That will have a large bearing on how you decode them. Python will not do either for you if you step beyond dicts, lists, unicode, strings, ints, floats, booleans, and `None`.

The canonical way to encode custom classes is to subclass `json.JSONEncoder` and provide a `default` method. The `default` method has signature `'self, obj'` and returns `obj` encoded in json if it knows how to and returns `super(clsname, self).default(obj)` if does not.

If you encode your classes as dicts, then you can write a function that accepts one argument (a decoded dictionary) and returns the decoded object from that. Then pass this function to the constructor for `json.JSONDecoder` and use the `decode` method on that instance.

All in all, json is not ideally suited for serializing complex classes. If you can capture the entire state of a function in such a way that it can be passed to the init method, then have at it but if not, then you'll just hurt your head trying.